# Template Literals - Changing the Inner HTML of an element (onInput event)

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals

So I´ve never used Template Literals before, but I need to work with a template now that seemingly includes a form with Template Literals

This is one of my inputs:

```
<input
        type="number"
        className="mf-input "
        min="1900"
        max="2099"
        step="1"
        id="curyear"
        name="currentyear"
        placeholder="${ parent.decodeEntities(`Current Year`) } "
        onInput=${parent.handleChange}
        aria-invalid=${validation.errors['currentyear'] ? 'true' : 'false'}
        ref=${el => parent.activateValidation({"message":"This field is required.","minLength":1900,"maxLength":2099,"type":"by_character_length","required":false,"expression":"null"}, el)}
            />

            <${validation.ErrorMessage}
          errors=${validation.errors}
          name="currentyear"
          as=${html`<span className="mf-error-message"></span>`}
          />
```

What I am trying to do is, in the onInput method, instead of handling the validation, I also want to change the innerHTML of an element:

```
  <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default" id="curyeartext">Current Year</h2>
```

I´ve been trying to do it for hours, but I can't get it to work.

EDIT: turns out, they are template literals and not reactJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by adding a function above the return:

```
  function myfunction() {
      document.querySelector('#curyeartext').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#curyear').value;
      document.querySelector('#lastyear').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#curyear').value-1;
      document.querySelector('#yearbefore').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#curyear').value-2;
    }
```

And call it in the onInput event handler

```
onInput=${myfunction}
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid setting innerHTML inside React, [use state instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). This is because React will overwrite your modified DOM when it re-renders, if the html is in a node that React is controlling.

```
export default function MyReactComponent() {
    var [ currentInput, setCurrentInput ] = React.useState();

    return <>
       <input
        type="number"
        className="mf-input"
        min="1900"
        max="2099"
        step="1"
        name="currentyear"
        onInput={(e) => setCurrentInput(e.target.value)}
        value={currentInput}
       />
       <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default" id="curyeartext">
          {currentInput}
       </h2>
    </>;

}
```

However, if you have a situation where it is unavoidable, you can tell React to ignore a node by only specifying a ref on it - i.e. no other props or child JSX:

```
export default function MyReactComponent() {
   return <div ref={divRef => {
      divRef.innerHTML = "Hello <b>world!</b>";
   }} />
}
```

This technique is typically used when integrating non-React specific JS libraries into React, as you can do whatever you want with the contents of that DOM node.